# Internal configurable IM client for corporations (with support for multiple protocols)

Tags: messenger

Last week a virus was passed on by employees using YM. It was a clickable link and yes ... some people just click.

I want to ban YM in the corporation and supply an internal IM, that's easily configurable and that has support for other protocols so that employees can see their YM contacts but cannot receive links from them. However, links may be passed on in with the internal YM.

Is that possible? Any other way around problems like this? One major requirement would be to allow YM so that employees can chat with clients.

Comment: YM being Yahoo! Messenger, I assume?

Comment: Indeed...........

Comment: Would it be easier to restrict malicious links using your firewall rather than manipulating the IM client? I've checked Pidgin/kopete but I can't see any immediate way of restricting links for certain contacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a discussion on Slashdot [here](http://ask.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=09/04/06/2243202) about open source solutions.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good resource on Slashdot, thanks. Currently looking into Openfire/Spark to see if the client can be configured not to open links (should be a per user config)